# Google map is not draggable/dragging even after making it true

Tags: javascript, css, html, google-maps

Google map is not draggable/dragging even after making it true.

steps to reproduce: load page with map in new tab, inspect and go to mobile view without doing anything. now in mobile view drag map left-right up-down, it will not works.

Please Run Code Snippet.

```js
      var map;
      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
          zoom: 8,
          draggable: true
        });
      }
```

```css
#map {
        height: 90%;
      }
      html, body {
        height: 90%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCk0vq10rCc-wxeYQb-E5IoB-E3WBtIMxA&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
<div id="map" data-role="page"></div>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask#
```

Comment: please note: this is only reproduceable on touchscreen devices, so just load the page and inspect > go to mobile view > then drag map anywhere

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried loading on an actual mobile device, or just using a responsive view via the web browser? I put your code in a JSBin and was able to reproduce the issue you describe using chrome developer tools. However, when I loaded the JSBin on my mobile device and tried to drag I got a message saying to use two fingers to drag. This has to do with gesture handling, which I will explain in the next paragraph.

The Google Maps JavaScript API provides a gestureHandling option in the MapOptions object that you can use to optimize your users' experience when interacting with the map. I believe the setting you want to use is greedy, this allows the map to be dragged with one finger, you can do this:

```
  var map;

  function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
      zoom: 8,
      gestureHandling: 'greedy',
      draggable: true
    });
  }
```

This will allow the map to be dragged with one finger instead of two. For more info please see this article:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/interaction#gesture-handling

One thing worth mentioning is that you will need to reload the page after selecting to go to mobile/responsive view. If you don't reload the page you won't be able to properly use the touch feature. This makes it seem as though the map can't be dragged. Once you reload the page this shouldn't happen. I'd recommend trying both on a mobile device and using a responsive view via the web browser. Here is the JSBin so you can see it live:

http://jsbin.com/tuvobipozi/1/edit?html,css,js,output

In order to keep your key private I took it out of the JSBin, please replace the script tag:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY&callback=initMap"
async defer></script>
```

Replacing MY_API_KEY with your API key. You will then be able to see the functionality. Once you select the responsive/mobile view please select the 'Run with JS' button to reload the page. You will then be able to use the touch functionality and see the map be dragged.

I hope this helps!